# show menu django-cms doesn't render anything

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a small problem. Everything in my django-cms seem's to work fine but the :

```
{% show_menu 1 %}
```

tag doesn't render anything.
I also try

```
{% show_menu 100 100 100 100 %}
```

At the top of my template page i have this :

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags menu_tags static%}
```

And in my admin interface, In navigation is check for couple of page.

Answer (score 0):

try: {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}

Comment: ??? i'm the author of this post ... I don't understand ?!? or maybe you want to talk to digi604 ?